# Declaring method signature with parameters

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass through a parameter to a method but having issues declaring the method signature to receive the parameter. I am trying to pass **mode** which is a string down to the **options method**.

Code:

```
const options: Options<object> = {
  padding: "dense",
  paging: false,
  search: false,
  toolbar: false,
  selection: true,
};
```

```
let mode: string;

 return (
    <MaterialTable
      columns={columns}
      data={productRows}
      options={options(mode)}
      style={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
      title=""
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: I believe this question is about react, but you haven't tagged it accordingly. Consider adding more relevant tags to help more people find out about your question

Comment: Noted will do now

Comment: Options does not seem to be a method?

Comment: Does it work if you combine via object spreading?  `options={{...options, mode}}`  I can't give a more detailed response without knowing the types of `Options` and `MaterialTable`